# Android build failed: Unable to find facebook-core:5.11.1

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

In the recent update of the facebook SDK, i got this issue while syncing the gradle file in android project (react native).

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> facebook-core:5.11.1 failed to resolve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make it work, you have to add following line to android/gradle.properties:

> facebookSdkVersion=5.11.0

to use the old SDK Version.

[Solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/676) by andrewzey

Answer (score 0):

Changing the versions to "5.0,5.11.0" fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Goto -> Gradle Scripts -> Build.gradle (Module:app) -> change your facebook dependency version from [5,6) to 5.11.0 and sync [check this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues/357)

Answer (score 0):

Changing following line

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)' to implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.11.0' build.gradle (Module: app) file

and sync

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my Case by changing the dependency to hardcoded worked.
I have use facebook sdk for login so,
`implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.11.0"`

Answer (score -1):

EMP fixbug: `node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle`

change from:

```
def DEFAULT_FACEBOOK_SDK_VERSION = "[5.0,6.0["
```

to:

```
def DEFAULT_FACEBOOK_SDK_VERSION = "[5.0,5.11.0["
```